# AngularJs - Ng repeat array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I can't understand why the next code is not working.

```
<div ng-repeat="r in reservations" ng-init="new = r.some_code">

<div ng-if="old == new">
  <p ng-init="sum = sum + r.cost">{{r.name}} - {{r.cost}}</p>
</div>

  <div ng-if="old != new">
      <p ng-init="old = new;">Total: {{sum}}</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Before that code I have an array reservations like the following:

```
reservations = [{name: client 1, some_code = 15, cost: 1000},
{name: client 1, some_code = 15, cost: 1000},
{name: client 2, some_code = 15, cost: 1000},
{name: client 3, some_code = 16, cost: 2000},
{name: client 4, some_code = 16, cost: 3000},
{name: client 5, some_code = 17, cost: 3000}]

$scope.old = reservations[0].some_code;
$scope.sum = 0;
```

As a result I get something like:

```
15 - client 1 - 1000 
15 - client 2 - 1000
15 - client 3 - 1000
Total: 0
Total: 0
```

I tried a bunch of times but with different wrong results. What I want is to display each reservation and if "`some_code`" changes, show the total.

How Can I do this?

NOTE: the array is sort by `some_code`.

Comment: why don't you calculate your values in a for loop in the controller, instead of poluting the view with model calculations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your array you have two client 1s, not sure if that it relevant.

I think it might be better to move this summation logic to the controller.  You could do create a hash with some_code as the key, total as the value.

It would look something like this

```js
$scope.reservations = [{name: client 1, some_code = 15, cost: 1000},
{name: client 1, some_code = 15, cost: 1000},
{name: client 2, some_code = 15, cost: 1000},
{name: client 3, some_code = 16, cost: 2000},
{name: client 4, some_code = 16, cost: 3000},
{name: client 5, some_code = 17, cost: 3000}];

$scope.totals = {};
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.reservations.length; i++) {
 if (totals[$scope.reservations[i].some_code]) {
  totals[$scope.reservations[i].some_code] += $scope.reservations[i].cost;
 } else {
  totals[$scope.reservations[i].some_code] = $scope.reservations[i].cost;
 }
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="r in reservations" ng-init="new = r.some_code">
  <div>
   <p> {{r.name}} - {{r.cost}} </p>
  </div>

  <div>
   <p> Total: {{totals[r.some_code]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can render reservations by some_code and then selectively show details. A way to skin a cat: [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/3fc43aae/)